# pipenv: "python-dotenv" reappearing after every pipenv install

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install, python-dotenv

every time i run `pipenv install` it will reinstall `python-dotenv`.
I was using `python-dotenv` for a while, but I want to use `django-dotenv` instead.

So, I want to remove it, hence i execute:

```
$ pipenv uninstall python-dotenv
$ pipenv graph | grep python-dotenv    // shows no output, so it seems to be removed
```

Now, I realize that it's still in the "Pipfile.lock" and when i run `pipenv sync` or `pipenv install` it will install "python-dotenv" again.

So I remove the python-dotenv block from the Pipfile.lock manually. I then run

```
$ pipenv lock
$ cat Pipfile.lock | grep python-dotenv
        "python-dotenv": {
```

which shows that it has added it again to the lockfile.
It's not in my pipfile and there is no transitive dependency to it - according to the pipenv graph

if i now run `pipenv install` or `pipenv sync` it will install it again.

I can't figure out why python-dotenv keeps reappearing and how to remove it permanently. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: have u also removed it from `Pipfile`, (fyi there are two file Pipfile and Pipfile.lock) you need to remove it from pipfile

Comment: pipenv uninstall would remove it from the Pipfile anyways, wouldn't it? and yes, it is removed.